# Openssh installed still Putty is not working properly

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ssh, virtual-machine, putty

I have setup 2 virtual systems of ubuntu using VMware player7.1.My physical system is running on Win7. Both the VMs are configured in Bridged Network mode. I am using wifi router in my home. I am able to access the internet from all the servers. Also I am able to ping each other systems successfully. 
OpenSSH-servers are installed in both the VM systems and I am able to connect each other VM systems through ssh.

But I am not able to connect any of of the VMs from my Windows system using Putty. 
Can any one help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved! it was an IP conflict between 2 systems initially!
Actually I have setup static IP for 1 of my VM as 192.168.0.103. But I forgot to do IP reservation in my WIFI router. So yesterday when I started my windows system, my router assigned the IP as 192.168.0.103 to my windows system. Then when I tried to start the VM with same IP, there was an conflict and hence putty from my windows system was not working.

Noticing this, I did a ipconfig /release and then ipconfig /renew in my windows system but still it did not worked. I did change the IP of my VM to 192.168.0.110 and restarted still it did not worked. I rebooted the WIFI router from admin console still it did not work.

At the end I switched off the Wifi router and all systems and then restarted them after 5 min approx . It then started working properly!